# C# PInvoke NtQueryObject Field CreationTime in ObjectBasicInformation struct is always 0

Tags: c#, windows, pinvoke

OK, let's get straight down to the point.

I'm trying to call `NtQueryObject` function in `ntdll.dll` to retrieve `ObjectBasicInformation`

I'll paste my definitions here:

```
[DllImport("ntdll.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern NtDllCon.NtStatus NtQueryObject(
    IntPtr objectHandle,
    NtDllCon.ObjectInformationClass objectInformationClass,
    IntPtr objectInformation,
    uint objectInformationLength,
    out uint returnLength
);
```

For the `objectHandle`, which is also the first parameter, I used the handle created by `CreateFileW` in `kernel32.dll`.

```
IntPtr handle = Kernel32.CreateFileW(
    @"\\.\GlobalRoot\Device\Harddisk0\Partition2",
    0,
    FileShare.ReadWrite,
    0,
    FileMode.Open,
    0,
    0
);
```

I'm sure `CreateFileW` works correctly.

And the parameter `objectInformationClass` is just an enum. To retrieve `ObjectBasicInformation`, I used `0`. I'm sure at least here I'm not going wrong.

For the third parameter `objectInformation`, it requires struct `ObjectBasicInformation`.

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct ObjectBasicInformation
{
    public uint Attributes;
    public uint GrantedAccess;
    public uint HandleCount;
    public uint PointerCount;
    public uint PagedPoolUsage;
    public uint NonPagedPoolUsage;
    public uint Reserved1;
    public uint Reserved2;
    public uint Reserved3;
    public uint NameInformationLength;
    public uint TypeInformationLength;
    public uint SecurityDescriptorLength;
    public ulong CreationTime;
}
```

And I passed the following `IntPtr`

```
IntPtr infoPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf<NtDllCon.ObjectBasicInformation>());
```

For the next parameter `objectInformationLength`, which is the size of the aforementioned struct, I used `Marshal.SizeOf<NtDllCon.ObjectBasicInformation>()`. The value is always 56.

The final `returnLength` is the value the function will return.

---

Well, so far so good. Let's take a look at the result.

The fuction returned `NtStatus.Success`. `HandleCount` and `PointerCount` matched the information I got using `WinObj`

**But `CreationTime` is always `0`, which makes no sense.**

I know its equivalent is `System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.FILETIME`. I also tried that, but still didn't work. Since the more generic `ulong` didn't work, I didn't really expect `FILETIME` to work safe and sound.

---

To be explict, here's the full code snippet

```
// NativeFile is the wrapper I created for CreateFileW and series of related functions.
// Just treat it as CreateFileW.
using NativeFile file = new NativeFile(
    @"\\.\GlobalRoot\Device\Harddisk0\Partition2",
    Kernel32Con.DesiredAccess.None, // 0
    FileShare.ReadWrite,
    0,
    FileMode.Open,
    Kernel32Con.FlagsAndAttributes.None, // 0
    0
);

int size = Marshal.SizeOf<NtDllCon.ObjectBasicInformation>();
Console.WriteLine(size);
// size = 56;
IntPtr infoPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size);
Console.WriteLine(
    NtDll.NtQueryObject(
        file.FileHandle, // handle returned by CreateFileW
        NtDllCon.ObjectInformationClass.ObjectBasicInformation,
        infoPtr,
        (uint)size,
        out var returnLength
    )
);
Console.WriteLine($"Return Length: {returnLength}");
Console.WriteLine(
    $"Creation Time: {Marshal.PtrToStructure<NtDllCon.ObjectBasicInformation>(infoPtr).CreationTime}"
);
```

--

Oh, one more thing. The system was Windows 11, 64 bit.

I googled about the function itself, as well as `ObjectBasicInformation` struct and some C++ code. But I only managed to call this function successfully, while `CreationTime` remains `0`.

I want to get the `CreationTime` of an object correctly.

Comment: Have you looked at P/Invoke.net? That's a wiki which is very useful when dealing with any P/Invoke issues: http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/ntdll/NtQueryObject.html

Comment: I know this website.  
And yes, it helped me a lot with my project.  
However, it doesn't work. Still getting a `0`.
The function did succeed though, just didn't return a proper `CreationTime`

Comment: CreationTime (FILETIME) is a 64-bit value, so a C# long or ulong

Comment: Thanks for your advise. But that didn't help much.

Comment: I took a look at my post again, finding out that there's something I didn't pointed out. The `ObjectBasicInformation` struct, I explicitly set its size to 56 `[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Size = 56)]` **in my code**, but removed the attribute accidentally in the post. So I removed `Size = 56` in my code and tested with `public uint CreationTime`, got NtStatus.InfoLengthMismatch, which was as expected. Then I changed it to `public ulong CreationTime`. However, the function succeeded with `CreationTime` still being `0`.

Answer (score 0):

OK, problem solved.
What you acutally need is `NtOpenSymbolicLinkObject` instead of `CreateFileW`, at least for a symbolic link object.
Here's the official document of `NtOpenSymbolicLinkObject`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/devnotes/ntopensymboliclinkobject

---

```
[DllImport("ntdll.dll")]
public static extern NtDllCon.NtStatus NtOpenSymbolicLinkObject(
    out IntPtr LinkHandle,
    uint DesiredAccess,
    ref NtDllCon.ObjectAttributes ObjectAttributes
);
```

```
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct ObjectBasicInformation
    {
        public uint Attributes;
        public uint GrantedAccess;
        public uint HandleCount;
        public uint PointerCount;
        public uint PagedPoolUsage;
        public uint NonPagedPoolUsage;

        [Obsolete("Reserved for internal use.")] [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 3)]
        uint[] Reserved;

        public uint NameInformationLength;
        public uint TypeInformationLength;
        public uint SecurityDescriptorSize;
        public long CreationTime;
    }
```

For the definition of `ObjectAttributes` and `UnicodeString`, please refer to pinvoke.net

---

Here's the full code:

```
var objectAttributes = new NtDllCon.ObjectAttributes(@"\Global??\D:", NtDllCon.ObjectHandleAttributes.CaseInsensitive);
var status = NtDll.NtOpenSymbolicLinkObject(out var handle, 0x0001, ref objectAttributes);
Console.WriteLine(status);
int structSize = Marshal.SizeOf<NtDllCon.ObjectBasicInformation>();
var infoPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(structSize);
Console.WriteLine(
    NtDll.NtQueryObject(
        handle,
        NtDllCon.ObjectInformationClass.ObjectBasicInformation,
        infoPtr,
        (uint)structSize,
        out var returnLength
        )
);
Console.WriteLine($"Return Length: {returnLength}");
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.FromFileTime(Marshal.PtrToStructure<NtDllCon.ObjectBasicInformation>(infoPtr).CreationTime));
Marshal.FreeHGlobal(infoPtr);
Console.ReadKey();
```

Maybe it's not elegant, but at least you can get the basic understanding of how it works

---

One thing you should be aware of is that `NtOpenSymbolicLinkObject` starts at `\` rather than `\Global??\`, which is not a commonly used path format for normal Windows functions like `CreateFileW`
For example, to access `PhysicalDrive0` through `CreateFileW`, you can simply pass `\\.\PhysicalDrive0` (`\\.\GLOBALROOT\Global??\PhysicalDrive0`) to it, while `\Global??\PhysicalDrive0` is the correct one for `NtOpenSymbolicLinkObject`
You can learn more about the structure of Windows kernel objects with `WinObj`